# How to arrange any word like bOReD - ORDbe this. So the problem is ı dont know how to call uppercase letters first

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string

For example:

```
mysentence = "He FeeL gooD"
....
...
print(mysentence) //HFLDeeegoo
```

When I print `mysentence`. I want to see "HFLDeeegoo" (First uppercase letters then lowers or numbers). Is there any way to do?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no attempt at solving this, also question is unclear.

Comment: But the question is easy. I want to print the first capital letters. For example my word is "woRK" but the format ı want to see is "RKwo".                                           
Or another example  : input: “yAS21OkuL4” --- result: “ASOLyku214”  @DannyVarod

Comment: Capital before non-caps, what about the order within each though?
Where is your attempt at writing code to solve this? If this is your homework/work you should not ask for an answer without trying first.

Comment: Off-topic: Note that the English first person singular pronoun is spelled "I" not "ı".

Comment: Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Convert the string to a list and sort it.

```py
mysentence = "He FeeL gooD"
mysentence = list(mysentence)   # str to list
mysentence.sort()   # sort
mysentence = "".join(mysentence).strip()  # list to string and remove any whitespace or trailing characters
print(mysentence)   # gives DFHLeeegoo
```

This works because when sorting a string containing alphabets, python uses the ASCII value of the letter. Uppercase letters range from 65 to 90 and lowercase letters range from 97 to 122. So uppercase first and then lowercase as the sorting happens in ascending order.

Comment: @DannyVarod "Don't answer questions without attempt to answer."                        
 What are you trying to say?

Comment: Thank you sir I was searching some commands in internet about like 2 hours. The teacher hasnt explained this topic(commands) yet.  Thanks for sharing your answer. Ofc ı wont copy-paste your answer I want to improve myself :) So it'll help me a lot. Have a nice day @sabz